# Simplify Recursive Function

Tags: python

So, i've been building this function but it seems to be a lit bit heavy if we input a big number in the arguments

```
def heron(n):
    if n==0:
        return 2
    else:
        return (0.5*heron(n-1)+3/(heron(n-1)))
```

How can I simplify it please? and can I call the function just 1 time instead of two? thank you!

Comment: Computing `heron(n-1)` twice definitely doesn't help, but this is a math question now not a programming question.

Comment: Yeah! i've been searching how to make it 1 call instead of two, but nothing

Comment: It stabilizes around `2.449489742783178` after just five calls, so there isn't much need to analyze it any further: `if n >= 5: return 2.449489742783178`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simplification is to simply *not* call itself so many times:

```py
def heron(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 2
    else:
        h = heron(n - 1)
        return 0.5 * h + 3 / h
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.9 or greater, you can use the `@cache` decorator from `functools` (see https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html). This saves previous calls to a function and will greatly reduce runtime. Using this in combination with @quamrana suggestion, you would get the following:

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def heron(n):
    if n==0:
        return 2
    else:
        h = heron(n-1)
        return 0.5 * h + (3 / h)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation seems to be `O( n ^ 2 )` efficiency. This is because for each time you enter the function with `n > 0`, the function itself is called 2 times.

One solution is instead of calling the same function twice, save the value of `heron(n-1)` then use it in both places. That way we get down to `O(n)` or linear time.

Example:

```py
def heron(n):
    if n==0:
        return 2
    else:
        heronPrev = heron(n-1)
        return 0.5 * heronPrev + 3 / heronPrev
```

General approach is to solve subproblems a single time, save result, and reuse. Rather than solving the subproblem each time you need the value.

This leads partially into dynamic programming algorithm approach. If you want to check those out a couple cool problems are Calculating Fibonacci Numbers in Linear time, 1/0 Knapsack Problem, Towers of Hanoi.